# Encoding issues with wordpress excerpts

Tags: php, wordpress, utf-8

So I am using wordpress 4.8.3 with the WP-JSON rest api plugin (1.2.5), and when I save post to the production server I get strange characters:

Gary Crossley FordÂ showed their generosity for their annual Fill The Bus event in partnership with Assistance League of Kansas City. â©The event raisedÂ ...

When I post to a local copy of wordpress the encoding is fine.

The same code is running on my laptop, and the production server. Both have php 7.1.11 installed from the ondrej/php ppa.  Both have php-mbstring installed.  Tables for both databases are using utf8mb4, utf8mb4_unicode_ci.  Wordpress DB_CHARSET for both is utf8.  Both servers are returning a content type of text/html; charset=UTF-8

What else can I check?

Comment: is your wp using a translation plugin?

Comment: No translation plugins.